# React-native :app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug FAILED

Tags: reactjs, react-native

when I did react-native run-android at 96% **:app: transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug** I get this error. I started to stop and I couldn't find the solution. Do you have any of these problems?

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ykstyt"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.0.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
signingConfigs {
    release {
        if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
}
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}

applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
compile project(':react-native-text-input-mask')
compile project(':react-native-admob')
compile project(':react-native-onesignal')
compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
compile project(':react-native-pdf')
compile project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.9.1, 3.99.99]'
```

}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Delete whole android folder

Run : react-native upgrade

accept y to finish.

After finish Run : react-native run-android

Thats All :D